# Getting 320V DC from 12V DC

Tags: power, voltage

I'm a photographer. A friend of mine gave me two big flashes, which I can use without grit. There is a generator, which generates 300-320V DC from 12V DC. This voltage loads the capacitors directory inside the flashes.

The big problem is, because of this he donated the flashes to me, the generator is oscillating in a very annoying audible whistle.

Now I'm searching for a circuit, to transform 12V DC or the better 24V DC (2 lead accumulators) into that 300-320V DC. The flashes are 300 Ws each. I hope it's possible to load them together in less than 4.5 seconds.

Comment: I attempted to improve the translation. Can you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by "...use without grit." and "2 lead accumulators"?

Comment: Don't know about the grit, but could he be referring to 2 lead-acid batteries?

Comment: 300 Ws/ 4.5 s =~ 67W at a00% efficient so around 100 W. You can build such yourself BUT 320VDC is about the DC bus voltage in a 12 VDC to 230 VAC inverter (as 230 x Srqt(2) = Vpeak = 325V. ) Buying a 100 (or higher) 12/230 VAC inverter and accessing its DC bus should suffice. As Asmyldof notes -  startup current when Vcap is low may be too high without current limiting).

Answer (score 4):

The original circuitry is a self-resonant system of a transformer with 3 coils and a transistor and some capacitances. This is used because it is simple and cheap.

The good news is that with modern core materials and a little more budget the same self-resonant system can be built at, let's say 35kHz outside of the audible range. And with very good power output. Many phone chargers do something similar, but from high to low.

I am not very in the mood for many self resonant calculations, but I have in stead used the awesome interwebs to find an instructable that isn't absolutely abominable. Be careful with the soldering of high voltage parts, try to keep large distances:

[Instructable aimed at charging HV capacitors] (http://www.instructables.com/id/DC-DC-HV-Boost-Converter/?ALLSTEPS)

**NOTE1: I have not completely read it, only scanned over it and determined it not to be terrible.**

---

EDIT1: From the comments from the above link, I lifted a more structured approach using a Linear Technology Chip. To be more precise: Their datasheet. They work through an entire example to create a high-voltage from a low voltage source:

[LT3751 Product Page](http://www.linear.com/product/LT3751)

---

**NOTE2: These high voltages and especially when put into capacitors can be life threatening.**

**NOTE3: If the source you built or bought is very strong (i.e. can supply quite a bit of power at the 300VDC side without dropping below 50VDC) you *must* add a small resistor between the source and the power capacitor. If you do not do this your flash tube may go into continuous conduction (when set to use full flash power / no TTL/FastTTL) on the power supplied by the power circuit and explode in a very small manner of time.**

Answer (score -2):

look for a Voltage Multiplier Circuit

assuming you have 12v dc you can go from

12v - 24v - 48v - 96v - 192v - 384v

using a 6 step voltage multiplier

Comment: Check the output impedance of that sort of converter. If you need microamps it's feasible but the OP wants about 75W to charge in 4 seconds.

Comment: adding a darlington array from the entrance to the end of the circuit in order for it to carry the needed current should be possible